# How to get multiple checked value from checkbox and prevent the output show twice

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-studio, android-checkbox

actually i am trying to create a checkbox that will show match recipe based on multiple selected ingredient. (some recipe may contain same ingredient) But i have no idea how to make the `if else` statement. so far,this is the code to show the selected ingredient, but it is not complete. someone help me with the `if else` statement please. thank you. (i'm using android studio)

```
  public class DessertIngAvail extends Dessert {

ArrayList<String> selection = new ArrayList<String>();
TextView final_text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dessert_ing_avail);

    final_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.final_result);
    final_text.setEnabled(false);
}

public void selectItem(View view){
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.checkBox153:
            if(checked)
            {if(!selection.contains("Bingka Cheese"))
                selection.add("Bingka Cheese");
            }



            break;

        case R.id.checkBox154:
            if(checked)
            {if(!selection.contains("Bingka Cheese"))
                selection.add("Bingka Cheese");

                if(!selection.contains("Steam Shrimp Paste Cake"))
                    selection.add("Steam Shrimp Paste Cake");

                if(!selection.contains("Banana Heart Cake"))
                    selection.add(" Banana Heart Cake");

                if(!selection.contains("Honey Frankincense Cake"))
                    selection.add(" Honey Frankincense Cake");

                if(!selection.contains("Ray Heart Cake"))
                    selection.add("Ray Heart Cake");
            }

            break;

        case R.id.checkBox155:

            if(checked)

            {if(!selection.contains("Bingka Cheese"))
                selection.add("Bingka Cheese");

                if(!selection.contains("Steam Shrimp Paste Cake"))
                    selection.add("Steam Shrimp Paste Cake");

                if(!selection.contains("Banana Heart Cake"))
                    selection.add("Banana Heart Cake");

                if(!selection.contains("Evergreen Cake"))
                    selection.add("Evergreen Cake");

                if(!selection.contains("Moss Cake"))
                    selection.add("Moss Cake");

                if(!selection.contains("Honey Frankincense Cake"))
                    selection.add("Honey Frankincense Cake");

                if(!selection.contains("Ray Heart Cake"))
                    selection.add("Ray Heart Cake");
            }

            break;

        case R.id.checkBox156:
            if(checked)

            {if(!selection.contains("Bingka Cheese"))
                selection.add("Bingka Cheese");}

            break;

        case R.id.checkBox157:

            if(checked)
            {if(!selection.contains("Bingka Cheese"))
                selection.add("Bingka Cheese");
                if(!selection.contains("Steam Shrimp Paste Cake"))
                    selection.add("Steam Shrimp Paste Cake");
                if(!selection.contains("Evergreen Cake"))
                    selection.add("Evergreen Cake");
                if(!selection.contains("Moss Cake"))
                    selection.add("Moss Cake");

            }

            break;



    }
}

public void finalSelection(View view){

    String final_fruit_selection = "";

    for(String Selection : selection)
    {
        final_fruit_selection = final_fruit_selection + Selection + "\n";

    }
    final_text.setText(final_fruit_selection);
    final_text.setEnabled(true);

}
```

}

the problem of the code is, i cannot erased the first output of the checked ingredient. so, when i enter checked ingredient for the second time, the value of the checked ingredient just keep added without removing the previous result.

Comment: what do you mean by "i cannot erased the first output of the checked ingredient"

Comment: As far as i understand your question, you want to remove entry from array list on check box click if it has that entry. If so, then use `selection.remove(" ")` method.

Comment: for example, when i run the code for the first time it show result, "moss cake". then i re run the code with different ingredient, it still show the "moss cake" even if its not matched the checked ingredient. understand? 

it happen because i don't know how to set the `else` statement to remove it.

Comment: @Shvet , can u show on how to insert the `selection.remove(" ")?` please

Comment: You should call selection.clear() before invoking this logic. Might be the selection here is static. First make it non static and just an instance variable. So for every execution it would be a new list provided you are not reusing the same instance. If you are reusing same instance of the class, kindly clear() the list before using the logic. Hope this helps

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy ouch it sound complicated and i don't know how. sorry..i am new to Java.

Comment: @SilverDamsel, Can you share your class once? I will try to answer it

Comment: Post your full code of class! Often We initialize array every time we call OnCreate method of class!

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy are u mean by java class?

Comment: Yes... I don't need complete class implementation. I just wanted to know if selection is static and also if you are reusing the class instance on every run. Man! The comments are growing!!! :)

Comment: above, i have edited my code to full java class.

Comment: i think you can do your  "selection.clear()" after "final_text.setText(final_fruit_selection);" line

Comment: @pooyan it seems worked! thanks a lot! i really appreciate it!!!! thank youuu

Comment: how to set the checked checkbox into unchecked in final selection? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

First of all use `Set` (HashSet) to avoid

```
if(!selection.contains("Ray Heart Cake")){
    selection.add("Ray Heart Cake");
}
```

Secondly I would do something like this. Set ingredient name as `View#setTag()` or in `Map<Integer, String>` where `Integer` is a view id:

```
public void selectItem(View view){
    Set<String> output = new HashSet(); // here could be ArrayList also OK
    for(CheckBox ch : allMyCheckBoxes){
        if(ch.isChecked()){
            output.add(ch.getTag());
        }
    }
    showOutPut(output);
}
```

This would make your code more readable and easy.